# How to pause and resume timer object

Tags: javascript, timer

I am making a timer, well I am making timers...basically you can start one timer for something but then the idea is that in the middle of that you might want to start something else so you can pause it and start another one and then when that is done, you can resume the initial timer.

The timer object is working fine and I can get multiple timers going at the same time...my problem is that when i go to resume the first timer it waits for the amount of time that the other timer has been going before resuming.

I have a basic fiddle of it here: https://jsfiddle.net/1ea07uv9/19/

My apologies for the code...I have been messing around with it trying to get it to work it has become quite the mess...it doesnt work exactly the way I have it in my local environment but it illustrates my problem....in the fiddle if you click begin first timer...wait about ten seconds or so and then click on timer one it stops...for about 10 seconds and then continues...I need it to just continue straight away.

Im pretty sure that it has to do with the lines:

```
var diff = (new Date().getTime() - currentObj.start) - currentObj.time;
currentObj.timerInit = window.setTimeout(instance, (1000 - diff));
```

where currentObj.start is now however long you waited behind?

EDIT: It was requested I post my code in this post instead of just a fiddle so here it is

```
//Array where jobs will be stored
var jobs = [],
    begin = false;

//Job object
function Job(name, active, s, m, h, elapsed){
    var currentObj = this;
    this.name = name;
    this.seconds = s;
    this.minutes = m;
    this.hours = h;
    this.time = 0;
    this.elapsed = elapsed;
    this.timeLimit = 28800;
    this.completePercent = 0;
    this.jobNumber = 0;
    this.timer = function(begin){
        var secondStr = '00',
            minuteStr = '00',
            hourStr = '00';

        currentObj.start = new Date().getTime();

        function instance(){
            currentObj.time += 1000;
            currentObj.elapsed = Math.floor(currentObj.time / 1000);
            secondStr = currentObj.seconds.toString();
            if(secondStr.length == 1){
                secondStr = '0' + currentObj.seconds.toString();
            }
            minuteStr = currentObj.minutes.toString();
            if(minuteStr.length == 1){
                minuteStr = '0' + currentObj.minutes.toString();
            }
            hourStr = currentObj.hours.toString();

            if(currentObj.seconds <= 58){
                currentObj.seconds++;
            }else{
                currentObj.seconds = 0;
                if(currentObj.minutes <= 58){
                    currentObj.minutes++;
                }else{
                    currentObj.minutes = 0;
                    currentObj.hours++;
                }
            }

            $('[data-job-id="'+currentObj.jobNumber+'"]').html(hourStr + ':' + minuteStr + ':' + secondStr);

            var diff = (new Date().getTime() - currentObj.start) - currentObj.time;
            currentObj.timerInit = window.setTimeout(instance, (1000 - diff));
        }
        if(begin){
            currentObj.timerInit = window.setTimeout(instance, 1000);
        }
    }
    this.pause = function(){
        clearTimeout(this.timerInit);
    }
}

//Create the snooze timer object and chuck it into the array
jobs.push(new Job('snooze', false, 0, 0, 0, 0));

//Begin specific timer
$('#timer_start').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    if(jobs.length <= 3){
        //Create new job object and push it into the array
        jobs.push(new Job('jobNameInput', true, 0, 0, 0, 0));
        //Loop through all of the jobs and give it a number (according to its array position)
        for(var i=0; i < jobs.length; i++){
            jobs[i].jobNumber = i;
            //Give the jobs their names but check we arent changing the snooze button!

    if(i == jobs.length - 1){
                jobs[i].timer(true);
            }
        }
    }else{
        alert('sorry mate...you can only have 3 jobs!');
    }
});

//Switch timer
$('.start').click(function(){
    var thisTimer = $(this).next('.time').attr('data-job-id');
    for(var i=0; i < jobs.length; i++){
        jobs[i].pause();
    }

    jobs[thisTimer].timer(true);
});
```

Comment: You might want to look at [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead. This will remove the need to constantly create a `Date()` object.

Comment: Please post your code here, right in your question, instead of only a link to it.

Comment: My bad...I thought as it was a bit long winded to get everything in I would just make a fiddle...plus I was removing a lot of unnecessary code for the question which i could test in the fiddle...@Tigger This might be exactly what im looking for as the Date object is proving hard to work with / not playing nice! I'll look into this thanks!